# Flex Mxml and property as string, escaping ?? Help

Tags: apache-flex, string, mxml

A simple problem: If i use escape characters for a property such as

```
<mx:Image  id="img" toolTip="\\foo{\\bar}"
```

It wont validate toolTip and therefore not compile.

What is the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ActionScipt for example in a creationComplete event handler and assign you tooltip and you won't have the same constraints as in MXML.

But you also can avoid these constraints in MXML by using CDATA:

```
<mx:Image id="img" source="foo.jpg" width="50" height="50">
<mx:toolTip>
    <![CDATA[\foo{\bar} or any usually forbidden characters as <, >, &, "'"...]]>
</mx:toolTip></mx:Image>
```

Comment: i think this is only approach http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=textcontrols_060_09.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML format for special chars.`<mx:Image  id="img" toolTip="&#092;foo&#123;&#092;bar&#125;"/>`